# How can I hide files in the browser, exactly in console/source/page?

Tags: vue.js

So I created a web page using Vue.js and deployed for production. Now I see that all my files are visible if I open my console in Source/page. I can see all my components, store, router, views, etc.

I would like to ask this community if this behavior is normal and safe? And if not what can I implement to prevent it.

I tried to prevent it using webpack but its not exactly working.

Comment: Yes, this is normal.  Any client-side code is visible to the client.  You simply shouldn't put anything sensitive in it.

Comment: In production sourcemaps are responsible for this. You can disable sourcemaps but then you won't be able to effectively debug minified code

Answer (score 0):

Front-End code is visible for everyone but you can prevent the generation of source maps in your production build by adding this config in `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false
};
```